# Insert a new line after the insertion point in Word for Mac 2016

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

In many apps on a Mac running macOS I can insert a new line after the insertion point by pressing this keyboard shortcut: `ctrl + O`. How can I do the same in Word for Mac 2016 using a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Ummmm, CTRL + O is "Open" as it is in almost every program on Windows

Comment: <shift><return> "Insert a line break"

Comment: <shift><return> moves the cursor down with the line. I want to maintain the cursor position, therefore mimicking the behaviour of ctrl + O in native Mac apps

Answer (score 0):

Command + 0 is the toggle I believe you might be after